# Stop ValidationRule if ComboBox is Collapsed

Tags: wpf, validation

I have two ComboBox's - cbo_client_pay_method & cbo_terms

One of the cbo_client_pay_method items (On Account) requires cbo_terms (30 days etc...) to be Visible else its Collapsed, I have this functionality already set up in cbo_payment_type_SelectionChanged event.

I have implemented a validationRule that test if the cbo's are not null && if selectedValue <0 (something is selected), this works ok.

This all works great unless the cbo's are collapsed, the validation still fires!

Can I halt the validationRule if the element is collapsed?

```
<StackPanel Name="sp_account" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Label Content="Payment" Style="{StaticResource formLabel}"/>
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox Name="cbo_client_pay_method" Style="{StaticResource reminder_cbo}" SelectionChanged="cbo_client_payMethod_SelectionChanged" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}">
            <ComboBox.SelectedValue>
                <Binding Path="client_payment_type_id" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <local:ValidCbo ErrorMessage="Select A Payment Type" />
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </ComboBox.SelectedValue>
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBlock Name="txtSelectPayMethod" Text="Please Select A Payment Method..." Style="{StaticResource cbo_overlay}" />
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>

<StackPanel Name="sp_terms" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Label Content="Terms" Style="{StaticResource formLabel}"/>
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox Name="cbo_terms" Style="{StaticResource reminder_cbo}" SelectionChanged="cbo_terms_SelectionChanged" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}">
            <ComboBox.SelectedValue>
                <Binding Path="terms_id" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <local:ValidCbo ErrorMessage="Select Payment Terms" />
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </ComboBox.SelectedValue>
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBlock Name="txtSelectTerms" Text="Please Select Payment Terms..." Style="{StaticResource cbo_overlay}" />
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

```
public class ValidCbo : ValidationRule
{
    private string _errorMessage;
    public string ErrorMessage
    {
        get { return _errorMessage; }
        set { _errorMessage = value; }
    }


    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        //if (this.ErrorMessage.Contains("Master") |)
        if (value == null )
        {
            // value = null
            return new ValidationResult(false, this.ErrorMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            // Not null
            int selectedValue = (int)value;
            if (selectedValue < 0)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(false, this.ErrorMessage);
            }
            else
            {
                return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could apply a style which only binds the value if the ComboBox is visible:

```
<ComboBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
                <Setter Property="SelectedValue">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Binding Path="terms_id" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True">
                            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                <local:ValidCbo ErrorMessage="Select Payment Terms" />
                            </Binding.ValidationRules>
                        </Binding>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ComboBox.Style>
```

You must *not* set the SelectedValue in the ComboBox itself or it will overwrite the style though.

Comment: Thanks H.B. This is exactly what I was looking for :-) BTW I can see you edited my question and removed the silly tabs, I have wanted to do this but I don't know how, any pointers?? thanks

Comment: VisualStudio: Ctrl + E, D -> Autoformat | Alt + Click + Drag Mouse -> Code Block Selection Thing

Comment: I was trying to do it on StackOverflow! Cheers for the help

Comment: @H.B. Hey, I really like your solution! In my case, I only want to validate visible fields, and I use multibinding and `Validation.HasError` property of each control to enable or disable button. The problem is, although I did what you have shown in this answer, even when my control is collapsed, the button is still disabled because control validation didn't pass. Is there any way to set `Validation.HasError` to always be `True` when control is collapsed? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @VasilijeBursac: Maybe you can trigger the validation when the control is collapsed, or remove the error manually. There the method [Validation.ClearInvalid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.validation.clearinvalid?view=net-5.0) which might be helpful. I cannot give more concrete advice since i have not run into this issue before (and these days i very rarely use WPF).

Comment: @H.B. Thanks for the answer! I am not sure what you mean by "Trigger the validation when the control is collapsed"? Can you explain a little bit more about how to remove the error manually? I tried to set `Validation.HasError` to `false`, but it is read-only...

Comment: @VasilijeBursac: I do not know how to trigger validation, maybe you can find the answer to that somewhere. As noted, i would try looking at the `Validation.ClearInvalid` Method, which should remove errors.

Comment: @H.B. Okay, thank you very much for your help and advice!