# How to disable validation of a combox element when visibility is collapsed?

Tags: c#, wpf, visibility, validationrules

I want to disable the validation of a ComboBox or a TextBox when their visibility is collapsed. Can I realize this within the XAML code?

```
            <ComboBox Name="XYZCb" ItemsSource="{Binding XYZ}" Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
                <ComboBox.Text>
                    <Binding Path="xyz" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <valid:ValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </ComboBox.Text>
            </ComboBox>
```

Button property binding:

```xml
<Button.IsEnabled>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource InverseAndBooleansToBooleanConverter}"
                  Mode="TwoWay">
        <Binding ElementName="XYZCb" Path="(Validation.HasError)"/> 
    </MultiBinding>
<Button.IsEnabled>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop ValidationRule if ComboBox is Collapsed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743127/stop-validationrule-if-combobox-is-collapsed)

Comment: I think this is a misunderstanding here @Andy . From my understanding collapsed is refered to the visibility of the whole combobox, not to the expander.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you need:

```xml
    <Button>
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=(Validation.HasError), ElementName=XYZCb}" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=XYZCb}" Value="Visible"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

Don't forget to remove your `<Button.IsEnabled>` binding.

Comment: Thank you so much. That's what I was looking for!